# How to read file path which is in the project folder itself in console application c#?

Tags: c#, html, file, server, path

`string strMailTemplatePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/EmailTemplate/HODEmailTemplate.html");`

This is the code I have written for reading file path.
But I'm getting the below mentioned error.

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Please help me to read the file path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: shingo, thank you for the reply. From this I'm unable to get any proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` is what you are looking for.

```
var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "EmailTemplate", "HODEmailTemplate.html");
```

See more about : [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.basedirectory?view=net-7.0)